# How to prevent same value of other combobox

Tags: javascript, php, html, combobox

I'm making a voting system wherein I have a senator position that can have a 2 candidate can be elected. All data are from the database and its hard to set if the first candidate was already selected from the first combobox.

```
if($rows!=0){
while($cols=mysqli_fetch_array($post_result)){
echo "<option   value='".$cols[0]."' >".$cols[1]." ".$cols[2]." ".$cols[3];"</option>";
}
$i++;
```

I want to have an output like this:

> President Juan dela cruz (First Combobox)
>
> First Year Senator Maria (first selected and the cant be selected
>   Maria on the next option) Maria (Next Combobox with same postion)
>
> Second Year Senator John (first selected and the cant be selected
>   Maria on the next option) Joshua (Next Combobox with same postion)

Hope you can help, thanks

Comment: Can you show how your table look like? Show all your rows you're getting. Without the data nothing we can do.

Answer (score 0):

You need 3 loops for each combobox:

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($post_result);

echo "<select>";
foreach ($rows as $cols) {
 echo "<option   value='".$cols[0]."' >". $cols[1] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><select>";
foreach ($rows as $cols) {
 echo "<option   value='".$cols[0]."' >". $cols[2] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select><select>";
foreach ($rows as $cols) {
 echo "<option   value='".$cols[0]."' >". $cols[3] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

if you need them ni sync you need some js, you can ask anther question.